# component interaction without parent-child relationship or service

Tags: angular

i have two components where one is an aside component with a search form and second component shows the data in a list view via an injected service. Now they are not nested and are independent of each other and i am trying to find out how can i filter the data in second component based on criteria from first component(search form). I know if they are nested i could use @input/@output property binding but how to pass data from one component to another when they are not nested. I know a service can be used to share data between two components but not sure how will it work in this scenario or do i need to change the architect and create a parent-child component structure.

Comment: A service can do this but you need to post the code for your components for you to get help.

Comment: Please post some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thing like:

```
<search-box #searchBox></search-box>
<search-result [text]="searchBox.text"></search-result>

@Component({
    selector: "search-box",
    template: "<input [(ngModel)]="text">"
})
export class SearchBox {
    text: string;
}

@Component({
    selector: "search-result",
    template: "<ul><li *ngFor=" ....."/></ul>"
})
export class SearchResult {
    @Input() text;

    ...
}
```